# Arabic text showing up after boot?

Tags: kubuntu, language-support

I am running Kubuntu, and after booting up my laptop, rather than English text, Arabic text shows up for date and time before unlocking it. I have changed language in setting yet Arabic text appears when I boot up my laptop. After I manually locking it, the laptop goes back to English.

**Note: This only happens when I boot up/reboot the laptop**

I am not a Arabic speaker, nor do I know much, and it would help to see English text on startup.

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu are you using? You may want to add a screenshot to [your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1397691/edit) along with the adding information about the Kubuntu version.

Comment: Also, did you accidentally select Arabic as your language when you were selecting the language? If you are not using an old version of Kubuntu, that would be the most logical explanation.

Comment: Systems language (desktop, menus, messages, etc.) and **regional formats** (date, currency, units, etc.) are two different and independent settings. You changed the former but not the latter, apparently.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, when I manually lock the laptop, I do get English text, this case applies only to booting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open your `/etc/default/locale` file for editing. Probably it includes settings for some `LC_*` variables including `LC_TIME`.

I suggest that you delete all the lines which start with

```
LC_
```

so the only remaining line is

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Then reboot.